# Mostar las entradas de una categoría de un blog de WordPress con Python

Tags: python, wordpress

Estoy trabajando con python y esta librería: [python-wordpress-xmlrpc](https://python-wordpress-xmlrpc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

Quiero recuperar de un blog mío todas las entradas que tengan una determinada categoría pero no soy capaz.

Si uso:

```
entradas = cliente.call(posts.GetPosts(
 {'number': noticias_mostradas, 'offset': 0,  'post_status': 'publish'}))
```

Me muestra las últimas pero necesito SOLO las de una determinada categoría.
¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?

Otra forma puede ser bajarme todas las entradas y filtrarlas pero me parece un poco cutre. Y tampoco sabría hacerlo.

Comment: proba agregandole los argumentos ( onda wp_query)  `'category_name' : 'post_category_name'` , o `'cat' : 3`

Comment: Gracias alo Malbarez pero no funciona nada de eso. También lo intente con 'category' : 'categoria' y nada.